# A bar serie next to a stacked bar chart with flot charts

Tags: javascript, charts, time-series, flot

Hi i have a stacked bar chart with time series like this :

[image: stack bar chart with time series]

But i need that yellow series to be next to the others like this :

[image]

I am not able to keep three series stacked while having another one not stacked and with an offset to the left. I tried different things but none of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this when declaring the data did the trick:

`data: theData,
stack:false,
bars: {show: true, align: "right" }`